# sql like pattern match numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I am trying to match sql pattern with like: **LIKE '%\"email\";s:[1-9]:%'**

The string in the database is like this: **"email";s:15:**

But is not working to see if between **s:[1-9]:** are any numbers greater than 1 or if there are any numbers.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex match.

```
where col_name regexp '"email";s:[2-9]:|"email";s:[1-9][0-9]+:'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `LIKE` comparison operator does not recognize regular expression syntax. It only recognizes wildcards `_` and `%`.

You need to use `RLIKE` or `REGEXP` (they're actually synonyms).

You can read about them here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html